# How can I use the WPF Toolkit Datagrid with XamlPad (latest version)?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, xamlpad

I want to work with a DataGrid in XamlPad. How do I reference the WPFtoolkit dll?

I've tried adding a xml namespace reference (below) but w/o any luck.

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: If you think Joseph's answer is correct, it would be good to mark it as the answer (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 6):

Try copying WPFToolkit.dll into whatever directory you have XamlPad installed.